# calling variable from flask to javascript and use for loop

Tags: python, flask

I am doing a flask project, and I am trying to call a list from flask and use a for loop to process the list in javascript. However, this does not seem to work.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    L.marker(["{{location[i][0]}}", "{{location[i][1]}}"], {
        icon: L.mapquest.icons.marker(),
    }).bindPopup("restaurant").addTo(map);
}
```

If I change `["{{location[i][0]}}", "{{location[i][1]}}"]` to `["{{location[0][0]}}", "{{location[0][1]}}"]`, this code will work. I am wondering if there is any special rule when using the javascript variable to call a list in flask. Please let me know if I should provide any other code. Thank you in advance!

Comment: flask and javascript can not interact. If you want to iterate over all the values from the python data structures you need to do that in flask and not in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate in flask:

```js
{{% for i in range(2) %}}
    L.marker(["{{location[i][0]}}", "{{location[i][1]}}"], {
        icon: L.mapquest.icons.marker(),
    }).bindPopup("restaurant").addTo(map);
{{% endfor %}}
```

I have not tested this example and I don't know your project but it shows the method in priciple.